# Why am I seeing negative hours in the Reopen Votes review queue?

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

It's probably just a UI thing, but it sure looks like I am seeing "negative" hours in [the Reopen Votes review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22532812):

[image]

Of course, I'm pretty sure this is not really supposed to be read as "negative 9 hours", but at an initial glance, it reads that way.  Could the hyphen simply be removed?

Comment: Does it show the author before the hyphen?

Comment: No, is it supposed to?  See the screenshot in my post, that's exactly how it appears.

Comment: Then it isn't supposed to, you're right. If an author was before it then it would make sense.

Comment: Maybe it's showing questions that will be closed in the future? ;-)

Comment: It is `- 9 hours ago -`, not `-9 hours ago -`, so it is not intended as a minus IMO.

Comment: Currently, it's already *-16* hours...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I agree.  Just at a preliminary glance it looks like minus 9, and it _seems_ to be unnecessary.

Comment: So I guess `- yesterday` means `tomorrow`

Comment: I think we have an audit here... wait, that's not an audit, but there's still an empty username. Also, the edit was made by the OP, not a now-deleted user.

Comment: No author here either. Sounds like a UI bug. Repro'd on other posts too

Comment: `- 30 years ago` means `30 years from now`.

Comment: "Sounds like a UI bug." Sounds like a feature!

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely a UI bug, as that '-' should only appear after an author's name.

Still, as @Mark Rotteveel notes, It is `- 9 hours ago -`, `not -9 hours ago -` or `-9 hours ago`

The UI could probably be made less confusing if the en-dash (alt + dash on mac) or em-dash (shift + alt + dash) were used instead of '-'. This is a longer dash that looks like –, compared to -.

Comment: There are hyphens, en-dashes, and em-dashes, in increasing order of "long-ness". That should be an em-dash, which is used for separating phrases. En-dashes are used for separating spans of numbers. On the Mac, which is what you apparently use, Option+Hyphen inserts an en-dash; Shift+Option+Hyphen inserts an em-dash.

Comment: Which dash is currently being used? Hyphen or en-dash?

Comment: It's a lowly hyphen, because that's all most people know how to type. Especially Windows programmers, who have to do all sorts of awful contortions, like Alt+0150 for the en-dash and Alt+0151 for the em-dash. Or `&ndash;` and `&mdash;` in contexts that support HTML escapes (which unfortunately does *not* include Stack Exchange comment mini-markdown). Also, most people aren't typography geeks.

Comment: `-9 hours ago` is 9 hours from now, in the future, right? 