# Let's dash the [hyphen] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I recently came across the tag [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen), defined as:

> The hyphen character, also known as the dash or minus sign.

To me, this seems equivalent of having a tag like `?` or even `e` for that matter. Is there some meaning I am missing for this, or can we burninate? [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) experts, please advise.

Comment: Interesting that some users use that tag for their Dash (a python library) questions.

Comment: @Tom That is likely because `dash` is a tag synonym for hyphen.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat such confusion makes it seem likely this 'hyphen' tag does more harm than good

Comment: So.. if this tag is the target of another tag, that is legitimate, that should probably be dealt with first, no?

Comment: dash is also an acronym for Debian Almquist Shell. Such an ambiguous tag shouldn't be a synonym of anything. That aside I don't know what we need the hyphen tag for.

Comment: wonder how would a golden badge holder in this tag look like. Can one be an expert in hyphen?

Comment: @gnat I'd imagine they'd answer a lot of questions about em-dashes confusing ASCII-only apps ...

Comment: [relevant meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381434/5762332)

Comment: @Magnetron That entire Q&A pair is useful here; it sounds like this tag should go. "Questions involving a dash character" (or hyphen, as it were) aren't a useful subset for anyone; they're much better categorized under their respective topics/ libraries/ language constructs/ etc.

Comment: @zcoop98 I agree with you, but if your argument is true, then at least half our tags are useless.  For example, we've got tags for `while` loops and `for` loops, as if there are people interested in answering questions about one and not the other!

Comment: @Steve This is true, but at least there can be questions that directly revolve around those constructs– I'm hard pressed to believe we have more than a handful of questions which are specifically about hyphens.

Comment: Having answered a few [Plotly-Dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly-dash) questions I can confirm that Abdul Aziz Barkat is absolutely correct in that `hyphen` is *never* used as a tag for `Plotly Dash` questions on purpose. Only as a mis-hap because `dash` is [set up as a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hyphen/synonyms) for `hyphen`. So a little correction in that regard would be great.

Comment: I can see a remote edge case for splitting words across lines in a text processing algorithm, but `soft-hyphen` handles that, and `hyphenation` is probably relevant.  In no case should there be a tag for a character otherwise, but I wouldn't argue against synonomizing it with one of these two.

Comment: `hyphen` has to be removed and instead set of language-specific tags should be used if really necessary. Similar to [tag:null-coalescing-operator] (for `??` in C#), [tag:null-conditional-operator] (for `?.` in C#), etc. All those have *better* names explaining the purpose rather than just general name for a characters used. Specifically for `-` In C# one could add tag for [minus operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/minus-operator), but noone seems require that.

Comment: given that it has ~470 questions, shouldn't we make it a proper burnination request? With some disambiguation in the meantime to salvage ones that have better-suited alternative tags. Anyways, count another one supporting vote.

Comment: I have been fixing many questions that were wrongly tagged `hyphen`, most of which were caused by the `dash` synonym. Most of these come from confusion with the tag `plotly-dash`, but there are also some targeting `mpeg-dash` and `dash-shell`. Some also mean to use the `hyphenation` tag.

Answer (score 31):

An alternative to [Tyler's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408440/208273):

Burninate [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen), but not [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation).

Hyphenation is a common problem in text rendering and is a topic in which someone could have deep knowledge.

Hyphens are...not such a topic.

Comment: You only *suppose* that hyphens are not such a topic, but may I refer you to [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381640/why-am-i-seeing-negative-hours-in-the-reopen-votes-review-queue/381689#comment680789_381689) as a counter-example.

Comment: @CodyGray That's more of an argument for [dash] than [hyphen] ;).

Comment: Will the plain [tag:dash] synonym be formally reallocated, or will it just be available for reuse by whatever gets there first?  Or will it be blacklisted like hyphen?

Answer (score 12):

I have a suspicion this is a relic of the days when lots of LaTeX questions were asked on Stack Overflow. You ostensibly *could* have some people who were very familiar with working with specific characters there... and it contains several hyphen-related commands.

As has been mentioned in the comments, you can see the history of some of the related hyphen/dash tags [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266468/should-we-try-to-disambiguate-dash/381434#381434) when [dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dash) was disambiguated.

As it stands, however, I don't think we need a separate [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) or even [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) tag (Martijn's reasoning for [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) in the link above was for "programmatic generation of a hyphen", but we don't have (or need) tags for every other character being programmatically generated).

I think [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) and [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) should be burninated.

Comment: I don't agree with burninating `hyphenation`. It's not comparable to the programmatic generation of most other characters. There are multiple libraries that exist exclusively for this purpose. Looking at [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) for the tag, I don't feel that it fails any of the four [burnination tests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/14747239), in contrast to the `hyphen` tag.

Comment: @Michel *There are multiple libraries that exist exclusively for this purpose.* That's... a sad state of affairs. Perhaps we should just remove the hyphen from language altogether... might solve a lot of problems.

Answer (score 11):

[hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about breaking words with hyphens can be tagged [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) instead.
- Some questions are about a library called dash; **however**, there are several libraries/programs involved, and it's some times unclear which dash is being referred to. Might be worth leaving for an SME if you're in doubt about which dash a question is.

## Progress:

The [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=hyphen),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhyphen%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhyphen%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhyphen%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhyphen%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=408394)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) tag is missing a wiki and an excerpt so it's not clear to me what makes for a rettag and what doesn't.

The [hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphen) wiki currently says:

> [hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyphenation) for placing hyphens in words correctly

Should questions about the following techniques be rettaged:

- Splitting on hyphens?
- Cases where you're inserting hyphens?
- Solutions specific do dealing with hyphenated field names?
- Questions about a dash as well as those about hyphens?

Quite a few questions where about [css-hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-hyphens) but didn't have the proper tag.

(I'm keeping this list because it might also be useful to include in the tag wiki.)